# SQL SSRS Dataset hangs for single user

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssms

We have an SSRS report that runs a simple stored procedure, with 2 single-value parameters passed to it. Both the SSRS report and the stored procedure executed in SSMS returns in < 1 second. However, in the course of the last 2 weeks, there's been one user who has had the report not load twice. I've tried clearing the stored procedure's execution plan to no avail, and finally fixed it by just adding a dummy clause (1=1) to the sp to get the plan to change. The report works for every other user, including myself. What would be causing this?

Comment: Test using OPTION(RECOMPILE). If it works you have parameter sniffing issues. Also if your parameters are text, SSRS uses NVARCHAR. If your columns are VARCHAR, maybe conversion occurs and the optimizer is not using the indexes.

Comment: I did test this.. Dropped the sp and the execution plan, recreated it with Option(Recompile) at the bottom, and it's still not loading for that user. One parameter is a tinyint and one is a VARCHAR(10), I'll try to switch that up.

Comment: does the report fail or just show old data? I've had users using Chrome in particular that have reports that appear to be running forever but no activity on the server. Clearing the browser cache has resolved it.

Comment: He just gets the loading wheel until he eventually has to close it out. When running a trace on it, I see the RPC:Starting command but never get the RPC:Completed command. Nothing else hits the trace until he finally ends it. I can copy the exact wording that's in the RPC:Starting command and run it in SSMS in under 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

This might be 'parameter sniffing', in which SQL Server generates a query plan for a specific value of the parameter which works ok for that value but works very badly for some other values.

A trick to 'turn off' parameter sniffing is to have some local variables in the stored procedure that are assigned the parameter values before you use them.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetAroundParameterSniffing]
@SomeID INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @LocalSomeID INT;
SET @LocalSomeID = @SomeID;

SELECT *
FROM MyTable m
WHERE m.SomeID = @LocalSomeID;

END
```

This forces SQL Server to come up with a plan independent of the parameter value

Comment: I've dealt with parameter sniffing before, but typically it affected all users and I've never seen it affect a single user, much less the same user twice in a month. I tried the local parameter solution and it still hasn't fixed it.